# Python program keeps asking question again and again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a python intermediate and tried to make a text based adventure game in python. There is a class called NPC which has the NPCs. In that class there is a method called attack() which will attack the player and the player can also attack or defend. It is position based so the user can enter 3 things - 'high', 'middle' and 'low'. This is the code.

```
turn = True
        while turn:
            player_defend_pos = input('Where would you like to defend the attack? High, middle or low. ').lower()
            possible_positions = ['high', 'middle', 'low']
            attack_pos = random.choice(possible_positions)
            while player_defend_pos not in [possible_positions] and player_defend_pos not in possible_actions:
                player_defend_pos = input('Where would you like to defend the attack? High, middle or low. ').lower()
            if player_defend_pos == 'm':
                use_medkit()
            elif player_defend_pos == 'help':
                help()
            elif player_defend_pos == 's':
                shop()
            elif player_defend_pos != attack_pos:
                if equipped_armour == False:
                    print(f'You don\'t have any armour equipped so the {self.name} will do {self.damage} damage to you.')
                    player['health'] -= self.damage
                    if attack_pos == 'high':
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you up high')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
                    elif attack_pos == 'middle':
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you in the middle')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you down low')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
                elif equipped_armour == True and shop_items[1][player['armours'][0] + ' protection'] > self.damage:
                    print(f'Since you have {[player["armours"][0]]} equipped it will not do anything.')
                    if attack_pos == 'high':
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you up high')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
                    elif attack_pos == 'middle':
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you in the middle')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you down low')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
                elif equipped_armour == True and shop_items[1][player['armours'][0] + ' protection'] < self.damage:
                    player['health'] -= self.damage - shop_items[1][player['armours'][0] + ' protection']
                    if attack_pos == 'high':
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you up high')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
                    elif attack_pos == 'middle':
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you in the middle')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f'The {self.name} attacked you down low')
                        print(f'Your health: {player["health"]}')
                        print(f'{self.name}\'s health: {self.health}')
                        turn = False
                        break
            else:
                print('You have successfully defended the attack')
                turn = False
                break
```

This is the defend code there is a similar thing in attacking the NPC also which has the same output. Now even if I enter 'high', 'middle' or 'low' It asks the question again and again. Please show me some guidance.

Comment: `while player_defend_pos not in [possible_positions]` possible_positions is already a list.  Take off those brackets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. Try to trace through the logic of the code yourself, and see exactly where it is getting stuck. If you cannot solve the problem, try to create code that exhibits the problem, but is only as long as necessary. For example, if the code is stuck in a loop early on, then code that comes *after* that loop is probably not necessary - try removing it, and see if the problem still happens.

Comment: Where `possible_actions` is defined ?

Comment: possible_actions = ['m', 's', 'help']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. Actually I should have told that equipped_armour is actually a function. Sorry about that. I actually wanted the return value of equipped_armour() without running everything in it. So I searched my question on stackoverflow. Even that didn't work. So I searched for the global keyword, used it and then got the answer. Maybe your answers were right if equipped_armour was a variable.  Anyways thank you all for trying.

Comment: Did my answer help you realize that it worked if equipped_armour was a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
possible_actions = ['m', 'help', 's']

turn = True
equipped_armour = True

def use_medkit():
    print('Medkit!')

def shop():
    print('Shop!')

while turn:
    player_defend_pos = input('Where would you like to defend the attack? High, middle or low. ').lower()
    possible_positions = ['high', 'middle', 'low']
    attack_pos = random.choice(possible_positions)
    while player_defend_pos not in possible_positions and player_defend_pos not in possible_actions:
        player_defend_pos = input('Where would you like to defend the attack? High, middle or low. ').lower()
        print(player_defend_pos)

    if player_defend_pos == 'm':
        use_medkit()
    elif player_defend_pos == 'help':
        help()
    elif player_defend_pos == 's':
        shop()
    elif player_defend_pos != attack_pos:
        turn = False
    else:
        print('You have successfully defended the attack')
        turn = False
        break
```

Try something simple and then make it complex. The code above works for example.

Comment: I have tried that. It prints what I enter but still asks the question again

Comment: Let me know your thoughts on this latest one

Comment: No, sorry did not work

Comment: To be clear - did you try running my code above? can you describe further about what didn't work? The code executes for me when I run it on my local PC

Comment: Yes I have tried and ran your code. But no need to answer now as I have found out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in

```
# this will produce always true
 while player_defend_pos not in [possible_positions]
```

it should be

```
while player_defend_pos not in possible_positions
```

I hope my answer help your problem

Comment: Thank you for trying but it did not work

Comment: No need to answer now. I have solved it